# Drupal: unsure how a block has ended up on a page

Tags: drupal, view, openlayers

I've inherited an old drupal 6 site. I'm 2 weeks into understanding the whole drupal system.

I have a page which loads a branch locator map. It looks as if the map is a block created with openlayers and views.

The page where this block appears is in a 'Site Page' called 'branch locator'

If I go to 'Content Management > List' and then edit 'Branch locator'. I am able to edit the text that appears on the page, but there is no setting to add or remove the map block.

I can't get my head around how the map block has ended up on the branch locator 'site page'.

I have trawled through the menu system to see how these 2 are linked but don't seem to be able to find any clues.

I've looked in the blocks list.  I can see the block but when I go to configure it, there are no settings that get it to display only on the 'branch locator' page.

I also looked into the template files to see if there was a custom template for the branch locator page that was then calling the block into it, so far I have not found anything.

How else could this have been achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Your situation seems to be the perfect use case for the [Theme Developer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module.

There are endless ways to make a block show up on a page with Drupal, the module might not be able to find the one used in your case but it is worth a shot. Once installed, you'll just have to click on the block to see a list of candidate theme function/files, regular functions and files which may have outputted the HTML. [Here is a good example of what you'll get](https://drupal.org/node/209561).

If it wasn't enough, you may also find it by searching in your project for the node id, block title, HTML classes and IDs within the block, or even by looking for its content (text, URL, images). To do this, you can use your IDE's search function (for Eclipse, look into the `Search` menu, or press `Ctrl + H` by default), or even a simple grep:

`grep -R -H pattern .`

Where `pattern` is whatever you're searching for (nid, class, etc), and `.` is your project's root, modules or theme directory.